# Can't access localhost/phpmyadmin NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, xampp

I tried everything on the internet on error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 but it seemed can't to work. I have installed Laravel 5.2 on my computer and XAMPP too. I currently working on project and stuck on phpmyadmin. First, i use php artisan serve and migrate the table to my database and i open http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin/ and it seemed work. After some work(progress on project like seeding and php), i cant open phpmyadmin on my browser and it says NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161.It works fine when i stop the php artisan serve but when i use it again then it shows error.Can someone tell me how to solve this so i can access my phpmyadmin on browser?

Comment: You have to open this link  http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ and not  this (http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin/)?

Comment: i usually use localhost:8000/phpmyadmin because i configure the setting to call the port code. Before this happened, i can access phpmyadmin through localhost:8000/phpmyadmin.

Comment: This might be OT, but instead of *phpmyadmin* I would just use tools like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/de/products/workbench/) or [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/). At least for a DB on localhost. Last time I used *phpMyAdmin*, it was just too slow (in terms of reaction time). So I use *HeidiSQL* to manage the schema an data. And sometimes I use *MySQL Workbench* to visualize the schema for people who likes pictires more than code :-).

Comment: You should run it on a normal webserver. Using the built-in webserver will not behave as you'd expect because Laravel will take over and any `.htaccess` that comes with phpmyadmin will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have two different url i mean port for php artisan serve
and local server
some thing like this,

http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

http://localhost:8000/

don't access phpmyadmin from php artisan serve's server

Comment: i cant access phpmyadmin through http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ cause i call it in the configuration through port code. I usually access it through http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin/ and it works before i use php artisan serve. But after i use php artisan serve, it shows error

Comment: in xampp you can easily change the port to use different port like localhost:8080/phpmyadmin, php artisan serve creates a own server for itself, that's why this confilct is happening.

Comment: yeahh thanks mate. It worked when i changed the port. php artisan use port 8000 and phpmyadmin use 8080.

Comment: glad, it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

In Implicit call

you should define the route only once, Let me know if it works.

```
Route::controller('collection','CollectionController');
```

so now in url collection/home if being parsed then laravel will automatically call `getHome()` function

Comment: when i add that in routes.php, it shows error 
"Class App\Http\Controllers\CollectionController does not exist"
or i got it wrong way ?